# Webhook implementation | Doubts?

Tags: java, spring-boot, webhooks

There is a client to my server, which is calling a GET API to know all updates regarding a particular thing very frequently (let's say once every 5 seconds). Due to this there is unnecessary network calls are landing on my server even if I don't an an update to share.

I reached a decision to replace above approach with web-hooks, where I'll call there POST API whenever I have an Update to share instead of letting them put unnecessary load on my server.

**What I understand about Web-hooks**:

- A web-hook is **like a reverse API** which POSTs the updates to the server (The client which was calling our application frequently to know/GET updates).
- My client has to implement a Web-hook client, which is basically a POST API, I'll be calling whenever there's an event/update to be shared.
- I need to call their POST API using REST template wherever there's a new event.

**What I don't understand**:

- Is there anything called a Webhook server? If yes, how do I create/implement it? Any references?
- Is it just a reverse API, or is there anything special which both the server and the client needs to handle?

Answer (score 2):

Webhooks are usually used to notify other service that some event occurred on your side. This is made by standard HTTP request sent to some URL.

There is no specific thing like Webhook Server. This is standard application that sends request to someone proactively.

Should both services communicating with webhooks handle something special - this depends on your architecture, there is no "standard" here. You can implement any sort of retry or mechanism to validate that the other side received the information. Im most cases it is assumed that webhooks should be idempotent, so if two same webhooks are sent, the other side should not repeat their action.